# Order of stability of substituted benzyl carbanion

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, stability

> [image]

I think the order should be II > III > I. The +m effect should be more in case 1 than in 3, isn't it ? So, 1 should be more unstable than 3.

Someone please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a chemist, but I doubt whether the mesomeric effect is "*more in case I than in III*" as you put it.

I'm under the impression that the mesomeric effects (alone) in both cases activate the benzene ring to the *same* extent (If you try drawing the resonance structures, you'd probably feel the same way).

However, I suppose in case I, the minor $-I$ effect of the $\ce{-OCH3}$ group makes I slightly **more** stable than III (because the negative charge is somewhat diminished).

So to me, $\mathrm{II > I > III}$ looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is II > I > III because in II and III resonance effect will be same because resonance does not depend on the distance but since inductive effect depends on distance so *-I* of $\ce{OCH3}$ will draw more electron density than *para* position hence will become more stable. So correct order is II > I > III.

Comment: Isn’t resonance more important for stability than the inductive effect?